# Sharepoint (WSS) - searching for column values - how?

Tags: sharepoint, windows-sbs-2008, wss-3.0, windows-sbs, wss

I've created a document library in Sharepoint (SBS 2008/WSS 3.0). I did add a custom column (case #) to the list, and would like the users to be able to link to/search for documents with specific #'s. Is this possible out of the box with Sharepoint?

I did notice that the URL generated by filtering the list has the search term in it i.e.

https://sharepoint:987/testsite/testlist/Forms/AllItems.aspx?View={C1FCD9ED-5AE0-4307-A8DB-A78C50D60A9D}&FilterField1=caseno&FilterValue1=12345678

But how can I have the users enter the value in a search box? There will be thousands of documents in the list.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this list search web part:
http://www.infowisesolutions.com/product.aspx?id=ListSearch

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it via an advanced search, where you specify the column with your doc number in it as a search field your users can use.

You may also find that searching for the number in the regular search works - if this returns too many documents because your numbers are low (e.g. 1 would probably return a lot of docs that have 1 in the body) you might look at adding a prefix to your numbering system to avoid this.